# Search & Replace SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I am messing around with one of my databases.. is there away for me to search for a string in ALL the tables.. and replace it with another everywhere it occurs?

I am looking for SQL

Comment: please give an example so that one could be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use MySQL's Prepared Statements to do this, because first you need a list of tables by querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.  This list is string data types, which you can not immediately use as the FROM clause in subsequent queries.

Comment: ok so you are speaking french.. i know how to go around mysql and mess with stuff, but i know nothing about sql

i found the code to replace the string in a certain table in a certain field or whatever.. but i am looking to replace it everywhere with one statement :/

Answer (score 1):

There is no immediate SQL to do this, databases are not flat text files.

If you are trying to [learn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning) something follow OMG Ponies advice.

Alternatively, searching google for terms: [*mysql search and replace all tables*](http://www.google.ch/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=gAn&rls=com.ubuntu%3Aen-US%3Aunofficial&q=mysql+search+and+replace+all+tables&meta=&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)
gives as a first result on a first page a helpful discussion.